# C# WebBrowser: How to pass eventhandler's sender to a separate method?

Tags: c#, eventhandler, sender

I want to call some method in the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event handler, like this:

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
anotherMethodToBeCalled();
}
private void anotherMethodToBeCalled()
{
//doing something which needs to identify the sender 
browser...
}
```

Yes, of course I can directly put `anotherMethodToBeCalled`'s actions in `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`.

But I hope to separate that method in order to make the code easy to read.
This is a dynamic multi-tabbbed WinForms browser, so the specific sender browser cannot by staticly named.

How can I put the senderBrowser in anotherMethodToBeCalled()?

Comment: what do u exactly mean? You have a dynamically create WebBrowser controls and need to dynamically assign a DocumentCompleted event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question almost answers itself :-) . You need to add a method parameter to your method and pass the `sender` of the event to it:

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                                           WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   AnotherMethodToBeCalled( ( WebBrowser )sender );
}

private void AnotherMethodToBeCalled( WebBrowser browser )
{
   //doing something which needs to identify the sender 
   //browser.DoSomething();
}
```

The browser that fired the `DocumentCompleted` event is in the `sender` parameter of the event handler. To get an instance of `WebBrowser` you need to cast it to that type.

Comment: Ohhhhhh My....It was right under my nose but i would not see it! My question almost answered it, but that ALMOST is a long way to go for a noob like me, LOL. Thank you, Martin!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Happy coding :-) !